# unable to delete records in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have created a database that is displayed on the website and values can also be inserted. I was trying to delete the records.

This code is `create.php` and it created a form with `name` `age`, `email`, `num2` and `cal` (cal is just adding `age` and `num2` to see how the calculation works). We insert value and displays the database information that has a table called `info.` `db_connect.php` is connecting us to the database and using that database. `db()` is a function in `db_connect.php.`

```
    <?php



include "db_connect.php";




if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{    
    $name = $_POST['name'];
     $age = $_POST['age'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $num2 = $_POST['num2'];
     $cal = $age + $num2;

     db();
     $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO info(name,age,email,num2,cal) VALUES ('$name','$age','$email','$num2','$cal')";
     $insertInfo = mysqli_query($link,$insertQuery);
    if($insertInfo)
    {
        echo "works";
    }else
    {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }


 }



    $showTable = "SELECT name,age,email,num2,cal FROM info";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $showTable);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        echo "<table><tr><th>name</th><th>age</th><th>email</th><th>num2</th><th>cal</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>
            <td>" . $row["name"]. "</td><td>" . $row["age"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"]. "</td><td>" . $row["num2"]. "</td><td>" . $row["cal"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='delete.php? delete =$row[age]'>delete</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        } 
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "0 results";
    }

 mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

With every row there is a delete link that uses the delete page to remove the data before going back to create.php. This is delete.php:

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php"; 

$age = $_GET['age'];

$delete = mysqli_query($link,"delete from info where age = '$age'"); // delete query

if($delete)
{
    header("location:create.php"); 
    exit;   
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

I'm trying to use the age to delete data. If I hardcode the age. For example, if I write delete from info `where age = 21;` it works. all data with `age 21` gets deleted successfully. But if use this code, nothing happens.

Comment: Consider whether you really want to allow hard deletes via this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL contains `delete=$row[age]`, so you need to use `$_GET['delete']`, not `$_GET['age']`.

You should also use a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.

```
$age = $_GET['delete'];

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"delete from info where age = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $age);
$delete = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the spaces around `delete` in the URL.